# I cant seem to get HTTP request working on NodeMCU

Tags: http, arduino, esp8266, arduino-c++

My main problem is making the transition from this command which is obsolete:

```
http.begin("http://192.168.1.43/getUID.php")
```

to this

```cpp
WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;

String serverPath = serverName + "?rfid=" + content;
  
// Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
http.begin(client, serverPath.c_str());
```

What do I put in the client and server path?

Comment: What's unclear about it? You already have the `client` object and `serverPath ` is obviously the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start a session with `http.begin(client, serverPath)` and then send a request with `http.GET()` or `http.POST()`

So your code should work like this:

```
WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;

http.begin(client, "http://192.168.1.43/getUID.php");
http.GET();
```